# Disposing Singleton and Static objects

Tags: c#, static, singleton

As per the definition, static and singleton objects have a lifetime of the application. So, once that point is reached, how are the static objects disposed.

As for Singleton, we could still implement the IDisposable interface and perform a manual dispose the same doesn't apply for static class.

Comment: At the end, it might not be disposed at all if left to the GC. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203

Comment: "*how are the static objects disposed*" -- they're not. "Disposed" means calling the `Dispose` member of the `IDisposable` interface, and static classes can't implement interface. So the entire concept of "disposing" an object doesn't apply to static objects. If you have an object which needs to be disposed, it shouldn't be static

Comment: There could be problem if static object holds unmanaged resource. So yes, static object is "removed" from memory but unmanaged resource is still there.